# Convert Semicolon Separated Values to Columns - Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet of values organized by id number with a column of semicolon separated values.[image]

I would like the spread sheet to be organized by id number with a column for each value and if that value exists for a id number a 1 be placed in the cell and if it doesn't exist a 0 placed in the cell. [image]

Has anyone done this before or know where I should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this but you need to keep the original value somewhere and then use this formula:

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(C$1,$B2)),0,1)`

Your data layout should be like below:

[image]

So Column **B** contains your original data and your new headers starts at Column **C**.
Enter the formula in **C2** and copy to the rest of the cells. HTH.

Comment: Thank you! this answers my question exactly.